# HTML indentatinon in table

Tags: html, css, indentation

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    td.indent    {text-indent:10mm; }
//-->
</style>
```

[...]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="indent"> Long line of text </td>
        <td class="indent"> Some other text </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the output text in the table is indented as expected:

```
              Long line of text
```

However, when I try to add line breaks with `<br>`:

```
<td class="indent"> Long line of<br> text </td>
```

Only the part before `<br>` is indented:

```
              Long line of
text
```

How can I get the output to look like this?

```
              Long line of
              text
```

Comment: using padding is the first idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `padding-left` instead of `text-indent`.

```css
td.indent {
  padding-left: 10mm;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="indent"> Long line of<br> text </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue